Rails: commit inner nested transaction regardless of parent transaction rollback (requires_new: true is not enough)
Imagine an operation that needs to be protected against race conditions, and therefore is run inside a Rails with_lock block.
with_lock starts a new transaction.
In this specific case, we're not concerned about atomicity of the transaction, only about the protection against the block being run simultaneously (so we are only concerned about the lock).
The issue is that any rollback inside that block will rollback all operations performed in the block, which in this case is undesired. For instance:
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  
  def perform
    
    with_lock do
      expensive_calculation_and_persist_to_database
      some_other_operation
    end
    
  end

  private

    def expensive_calculation_and_persist_to_database
      ApplicationRecord.transaction(requires_new: true) do
        update_columns(result: 42)
      end
    end

    def some_other_operation
      raise # this will issue a Rollback, which will also rollback the #expensive_calculation_and_persist_to_database transaction, even tough it used 'requires_new: true'
    end
end

As you can see, we'd wish #expensive_calculation_and_persist_to_database to be commited independently of the rollback caused by #some_other_operation, so it wouldn't need to be calculated again.
Note that wrapping #expensive_calculation_and_persist_to_database in a transaction with requires_new: true does not solve it; Rails docs clearly state that it uses savepoints to emulate nested transactions, which seems that they would be useful for rolling back just the nested transaction, but seem to not be useful when we want the opposite (keep the nested transaction commited, and rollback the parent one).
Is there a way to achieve this desired behavior?

This might be of help: https://blog.dalibo.com/2016/08/19/Autonoumous_transactions_support_in_PostgreSQL.html#:~:text=An%20autonomous%20transaction%20is%20a,independently%20from%20the%20calling%20transaction.

are you calling some_other_operation a nested operation? In what sense is it nested? Looks to me like the second of two sequential operations. Am I missing something?

I wonder if the note in the docs for ActiveRecord::Transactions is still accurate. Postgres has supported subtransactions for a long time.

There is no way you can get that with PostgreSQL; don't try. I recommend that you do not use database transactions to serialize operations. Use some other construct in the language of your choice, or use advisory locks in PostgreSQL.

You can wrap the second method in a transaction as well:
# app/models/book.rb

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  def perform
    # joinable: false - is the same as `requires_new: true` for all nested transactions
    with_lock joinable: false do
      expensive_calculation_and_persist_to_database
      some_other_operation
    end
  end

  private

    def expensive_calculation_and_persist_to_database
      transaction do
        update_columns(title: "success")
      end
    end

    def some_other_operation
      transaction do
        update_columns(title: "fail")
        # raise propagates to the parent transaction block
        raise
      rescue
        # rollback does not
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
end

>> Book.first.perform
  Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
    Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = ? LIMIT ?   [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

    TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
    Book Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "books" SET "title" = ? WHERE "books"."id" = ?  [["title", "success"], ["id", 1]]
    TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1

    TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
    Book Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "books" SET "title" = ? WHERE "books"."id" = ?  [["title", "fail"], ["id", 1]]
    TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1

  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  commit transaction
=> nil

>> Book.first.title
=> "success"

